# Need to restart the app to show the first item added to recyclerView. Later it all works fine.

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

[I created a small app that just includes the problem I am facing. Video link below]

Problem: I have a `recyclerView` and a button that adds items to that `recyclerView`. On app's first start up the `recyclerView` is empty. If I tap on the button once, twice, thrice, nothing happens. Now if I close the app and restart it, I can see those items added to the recyclerView. Now if I tap the button again, the items gets added to the `recyclerView` as expected. This is not so simple so I have added a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDqNFwBgbO8) to show the exact problem.

I am getting nullPointerExeption at `data.add(0,i);` when I add the first item. To prevent that I placed it inside try-catch.

Here is some code:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private InfoTodayAdapter adapter;
FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fis;
List<InformationToday> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_today);
    try {
        adapter = new InfoTodayAdapter(this,getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

public List<InformationToday> getData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    fis = openFileInput("arrayListToday");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    data = (List<InformationToday>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();
    return data;
}

public void addWater(View view) throws IOException {
    InformationToday i = new InformationToday();
    i.volume = "100";
    try {    // I get a nullPointerException if I dont include this try.
        data.add(0,i);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    fos = openFileOutput("arrayListToday", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(data);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();

}
}
```

**InfoTodayAdapter.java** (Not needed I guess)

```
public class InfoTodayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InfoTodayAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<InformationToday> data2 = Collections.emptyList();

public InfoTodayAdapter(Context context,List<InformationToday> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data2 = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_today, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    InformationToday current = data2.get(position);
    String s = current.volume;
    holder.volume.setText(s);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data2.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView volume;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        volume = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `addWater` called from?

Comment: @akodiakson from onClick of button

Comment: @akodiakson if you are wondering which button i am talking about, see the video.

Comment: @akodiakson Finally I found the answer, I added it below, you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of workaround I found the answer.
When the app launched for the first time, it was creating an IOexception as the file with the `data` object didn't exist.

All I did was, the place where I caught the error, I add the things that were missing. As in, just made the following changes:

```
try {
        adapter = new InfoTodayAdapter(this,getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        data = new ArrayList<>(); // Added this line
        adapter = new InfoTodayAdapter(this,data); // Added this line as well
    }
```

voila! thats it.